# Getting Error : System.InvalidOperationException: User-Unhandled

Tags: c#, asp.net, razor, asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework-6

I am trying to learn to build a simple application by using ASP.NET MVC 5 and Entity Framework. I am able to add migrations and update the database. My application is working fine when it is executed. Below is the following code for my application.

CustomersController:

```
using System.Linq;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using WebChatApp.Models;
using System.Data.Entity;

namespace WebChatApp.Controllers
{
    public class CustomersController : Controller
    {
        private ApplicationDbContext _context;

        public CustomersController()
        {
            _context = new ApplicationDbContext();
        }
        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            _context.Dispose();
        }

        // GET: Customers
        public ViewResult Index()
        {
            var customers = _context.Customers.Include(c => c.MembershipType).ToList();


            return View(customers);
        }
        public ActionResult Details(int id)
        {
            var customer = _context.Customers.SingleOrDefault(c => c.Id == id);

            if (customer == null)
                return HttpNotFound();
            return View(customer);
        }


    }
}
```

Models :

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace WebChatApp.Models
{
    public class Customer
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [StringLength(255)]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public bool IsSubscribedToNewsletter { get; set; }
        public MembershipType MembershipType { get; set; }

        public byte MembershipTypeId { get; set; }
    }
}
```

CustomersView:

```
@model IEnumerable<WebChatApp.Models.Customer>
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Customers";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2>Customers</h2>
@if (!Model.Any())
{
        <p>We don't have any customer yet.</p>
}
else
{
    <table class=" table table-bordered table-hover">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Customer</th>
                <th>Membership Type</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
        <tbody>
            @foreach (var customer in Model)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>@Html.ActionLink(customer.Name, "Details","Customers", new { id = customer.Id }, null)</td>
                    <td>@customer.MembershipType.Name</td>    
                </tr>
            }
            </tbody>
        </table>
}
```

Migrations :

[image: Migrations]

Tables in the SQL server :

[image: Tables in SQL Server]

When i am trying to execute the execute and navigate to the customer module from NavBar the following error raising.

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'The model backing the
>   'ApplicationDbContext' context has changed since the database was
>   created. Consider using Code First Migrations to update the database
>   (http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=238269).'
>
> var customers = _context.Customers.Include(c =>
>   c.MembershipType).ToList();

Exception Image:

[image: Exception Image]

Even i checked with the Entity Framework from  PackageManagerConsole by Updating the target databases to the DBContext. Even i had gone through some of the old threads in StackOverflow   [System.InvalidOperationException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39814049/c-sharp-system-invalidoperationexception-error).But it doesn't work for me. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your database model is (for some reason) not in sync with your model.
You can try to run in package manager console: `add-migration test` and see if it will produce new migration. If it does, you just run `update-database` after that.

If that doesn't help, check this answer: [The model backing the 'DataContext' context has changed since the database was created](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28276571/the-model-backing-the-datacontext-context-has-changed-since-the-database-was-c?rq=1)